# Get name of table for a field

Tags: 7, entities

I've been using EntityFieldQuery to query my fields but I need the SQL 'like' operator.  For this I'm querying the database manually.  Question:  How do I get the name of a field's table?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but are you saying that EntityFieldQuery does not support the like operator? I haven't done much with EFQ yet, but the code at [EntityFieldQuery::addCondition](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3AaddCondition/7) looks like it should be supported.

Comment: What if I want to select field values? Not nodes based on field values, but the actual field values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to use is the [`fieldCondition`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3AfieldCondition/7)
, which works pretty much like `entityCondition` and `propertyCondition`, only you are adding a condition for the field and not the entity or one of it's properties.

This is how you should query fields and entities.

If you wanted to get info about the how the data of a field was stored, that information is available on the field itself. So you could do

```
$field = field_info_field('field_name');
$storage_details = $field['storage']['details'];
```

What info you get depends on how the field is stored, as Drupal support multiple storage backends for fields.

Comment: the storage details array is not specified anywhere. Calling  _field_sql_storage_tablename and _field_sql_storage_coulmname directly is also ugly because they are specified as private method but still safer than messing with that array.

Comment: hook_update_N *breaks* with the code above. Use `_field_sql_storage_tablename` as I said.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way for obtaining storage details - field_info_fields() function.
If you need to get more than one table (data and revisions in your situation) you may use it

```
$fields = field_info_fields();
$field_current_tbl_name = array_keys($fields[FIELD_NAME]['storage']['details]['sql']['FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT']);
$field_revision_tbl_name = array_keys($fields[FIELD_NAME]['storage']['details]['sql']['FIELD_LOAD_REVISION']);
```

Don't forget that field_info_fields() - memory eater, so it is better to use field_info_field() if you need only single field data.